# Format number with commas in Django admin tabular inline

Tags: django, tabular

How can I format numbers with commas in Django admin tabular inline?
Example:
100000 => 100,000

Here I have an text input with numbers on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9Z9.png

Comment: Take a look to `django.contrib.humanize`. Maybe you can apply this filter to fields in a AdminTabular.